# Decode serialized data - possibly google protobuff

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

I feel like I've tried everthing..
I have a file saved by some proprietary software. I would like to create my own file compatible with the software so I reached out to the developer.
The developer of this software stated that the saved file was created using google protocol buffers, but was unable to comprehend my request for the .proto file used. He also insisted that it was google protobuf that was used, and doesn't want to help me any further.
I've tried a few deoce tehniques found online but nothing seems to be reading any data from the file.

Can anyone help me open and edit this file?

https://filebin.ca/5lTSezDweL3w

Any help in the drection of doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The header says "GPB2" but after some digging I wasn't able to confirm that protobuf uses this magic string.  As you know, protobuf is not self-describing, which means it's just binary data.  You might be able to do some heuristic by looking at all the nulls and see if that points to one data type or another.  What you could do is to change a variable in the program, and compare the file against the previously saved file.  Then reverse engineer what the .proto file should be.

Comment: I did just find that someone picked this apart before and used protobuf:
https://www.memotech.franken.de/FileFormats/Navico_Map_Creator_Project_Format.pdf

But i'm unsure how to go about creating a proto file to work with these files easily.
I do understand that it's not self describing, but I can't seem to pull any raw data from this file, even a raw dump using protoc.

Comment: You will have to create the .proto file yourself if you cannot find it.  Remember the header, "GPB2", well, the pdf you shared tells you that this is "Insight Map Creator V0.7.4.x format" (p. 9).  It tells you the first field of the header is a uint which appears to be a sfixed64, followed by a varint which is probvably a uin64.  It's supposed to a length so you can decode it to see if that matches up.  It's tedious but the pdf makes this much easier.

Comment: Does it complain of data errors if you run it through https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode ? If it doesn't (i.e. it shows data, even if you can't understand it yet), I can probably help you reverse engineer a schema

Comment: No it doesn't show anything